# How to design my python application to work in parallel across multi-cores

Tags: python, python-multithreading, eventlet, green-threads

As far as I know, in Python, if you used normal threading in a multi-core environment, GIL normally gets on the way and affects the performance in a negative way(because threads would be trying to acquire and release GIL constantly and doing a lot of context-switching between threads/processors).

That's why a lot of people starts using green threads, e.g. eventlet. The eventlet library allows you to have multiple green threads working together cooperatively and works perfectly in a single processor(less synchronisation issue, quick spawning/efficiency etc etc).

My question is that if I had a multi-core OS and were to design my python application, what's the best practice or design pattern I should follow to take advantages of both cooperative threading(green threads) and multi-core processors.

Comment: Dead simple: IO bound == threads, CPU bound == process. Also, Python 3.2+ threads perform much better than earlier versions, like 2.7

Comment: @JBernardo can you provide an answer and explain why in details? also why you say thread, you meant threading or green threads? Some concrete examples are highly appreciated.

Comment: Threads, like those from the `threading` library. I'm afraid this question is too broad for SO format... You should add some real examples of what you want to do.

Comment: Python 2.7 only simulates threads, while python >3 has native threads, meaning they can take advantage of multi-core processors. If you really have to use threads, go for python >3. If you can't do that, try to spawn more processes and make them cooperate instead of threads.

Comment: @IonutHulub can you provide a reference for that? I've never heard it.

Comment: @IonutHulub That's really wrong. Python always had real threads. Just the GIL was improved on Python 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very general approach, which I first saw in tech talk on Youtube growth [1] is this: identify and fix your bottlenecks, drink, sleep, etc, continue with bottlenecks again.

So, *when* you've got too much work and cores sit idle, well, run more processes. Using the same approach you'll know when to stop or even shrink process pool.

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZW5_eEKEC28

Comment: can you provide the youtube link as part of your answer? thanks:)